# index column with datatype date

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to index a column "left", that has the datatype date

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (left);
```

but there occurs following ERROR message:

```
Error:  Syntaxerror on »)«
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (left);
```

Comment: So which is it? Mysql, Postgresql or Postgis?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: Double-quoted escape it is, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If postgres, then

```
 CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table ("left");
```

If mysql

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (`left`);
```

And better, don't use reserved words in  inappropriate places, at all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe left is a key word. Escape left in ur statement

Comment: By `escape` they mean surround it with the proper quotes, like `\`` in MySQL or `"` (double-quote) in any other database.